# Why does recvmsg not accept MSG_CTRUNC as a flag?

Tags: linux, networking, syscalls

according to `man 2 recv` `recvmsg` may return `MSG_TRUNC`

```
   MSG_TRUNC
          indicates that the trailing portion of a datagram was dis‐
          carded because the datagram was larger than the buffer sup‐
          plied.
```

because sometimes we want to know the size of the buffer we would need to allocate `MSG_TRUNC` may also be used as a parameter in the `flags` field

```
   MSG_TRUNC (since Linux 2.2)
          For raw (AF_PACKET), Internet datagram (since Linux
          2.4.27/2.6.8), netlink (since Linux 2.6.22), and UNIX datagram
          (since Linux 3.4) sockets: return the real length of the
          packet or datagram, even when it was longer than the passed
          buffer.
```

the documentation also states `recvmsg` may also return `MSG_CTRUNC`

```
   MSG_CTRUNC
          indicates that some control data were discarded due to lack of
          space in the buffer for ancillary data.
```

and yet there is no way to get the real length of the ancillary data.
shouldn't recvmsg accept `MSG_CTRUNC` so that we can get the real size of the ancillary data?

Comment: The `MSG_TRUNC` parameter flag is a Linux extension, it's not in POSIX.

Comment: then why not extend it to include MSG_CTRUNC

Comment: Good question, but it would probably be more appropriate as a Linux bug report than a question in SE.